# Function Stops Processing with Try Catch

Tags: powershell

Why does this function stop processing even though I am using try/catch and continue statement?

In the following example when "three" is reached I attempt an invalid Get-Item with the hope that the ErrorAction Stop statement will be caught then continue on to "four" and "five".

The result should be

```
one
two
four
five
```

but instead I only get the first two values

```
one
two
```

---

```
function Get-Array {

    [CmdletBinding(
        SupportsShouldProcess=$false, ConfirmImpact='Medium'
    )]
    param(

        [string[]] $myArray

    )

    begin{

        Set-StrictMode -Version latest

        Write-Verbose ('[{0}] Processing begun ...' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand)

        Write-Verbose ("Procesing {0} items" -f $myArray.Count)

    }

    process{

        $myArray | ForEach-Object {

            if($_ -eq "three"){

               try
               {
                    Get-Item -Path "x:\foo" -ErrorAction Stop
               }
               catch [System.Exception]
               {
                    Write-Error $_
                    continue;
               }
            } 

            Write-Output $_
        }

        }

    end{

        Write-Verbose ('[{0}] Processing completed.' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand)
    }

}


$input = @("one","two","three","four","five")
$result = Get-Array -myArray $input -verbose -InformationVariable $info
$result 

# Expect: "one","two","four","five"
# Actual: "one","two"
```

Comment: Read `Get-Help about_automatic_variables` why you should **not** use some variable names like `$input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is in a pipe the continue exits the pipe and trys to move on to the next object in the array above the object. Instead use a Return which will return to the next object in the pipe

Continue will work in this situation :

```
foreach($item in $OutsideArray){
    if($item -eq "three"){
        continue
    }
    $item
}
```

Return will work in this one :

```
$InsideArray  = @("one","two","three","four","five")
$InsideArray | ForEach-Object {    
    if($_ -eq "three"){    
        try
        {
            Get-Item -Path "x:\foo" -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch [System.Exception]
        {
            Write-Error $_
            return
        }
    }     
    Write-Output $_
}
```

In this last example below you will see that when you hit the continue in the pipe it will go to the next item in the **$OutsideArray**. It never hits the **"Outside End"** statement because the Pipe forces the **ForEach** to move to next number.

```
foreach($item in $OutsideArray){
    "Outside Start :  $item"
    $InsideArray  = @("one","two","three","four","five")
    $InsideArray | ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -eq "three"){
            try
            {
                Get-Item -Path "x:\foo" -ErrorAction Stop
            }
            catch [System.Exception]
            {
                continue
            }
        } 
        "Inside : $_"
    }
    "Outside End :  $item"
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow some of the explanation i.e. "continue exits the pipe and trys to move on to the next object in the array above the object" and I am not sure that example is close to mine.   I did get what you are saying about replacing the continue statement with the return statement and now works as expected.

Comment: @ChiliYago If this answer solved your problem please make it as the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea could only work in case

- the Write-Output,
- the whole if with the attempt to Get-Item

are **inside** the try catch block.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\28\SO_51089096.ps1

function Get-Array {
    [CmdletBinding(
        SupportsShouldProcess=$false, ConfirmImpact='Medium'
    )]
    param(
        [string[]] $myArray
    )
    begin{
        Set-StrictMode -Version latest
        Write-Verbose ('[{0}] Processing begun ...' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand)
        Write-Verbose ("Procesing {0} items" -f $myArray.Count)
    }
    process {
        $myArray | ForEach-Object {
            try {
                if($_ -eq "three"){
                    Get-Item -Path "x:\foo" -ErrorAction Stop
                }
                Write-Output $_
            } catch [System.Exception] {
                    Write-Error $_
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        Write-Verbose ('[{0}] Processing completed.' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand)
    }
}

$MyInput = @("one","two","three","four","five")
$result = Get-Array -myArray $MyInput -verbose -InformationVariable $info
$result
# Expect: "one","two","four","five"
# Actual: "one","two"
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\06\28\SO_51089096.ps1
AUSFÜHRLICH: [Get-Array] Processing begun ...
AUSFÜHRLICH: Procesing 5 items
```

> ```
> Get-Array : Das Laufwerk wurde nicht gefunden. Ein Laufwerk mit dem Namen "x" ist nicht vorhanden.
> In Q:\Test\2018\06\28\SO_51089096.ps1:34 Zeichen:11
> + $result = Get-Array -myArray $MyInput -verbose -InformationVariable $ ...
> +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-Array
> ```

```
AUSFÜHRLICH: [Get-Array] Processing completed.
one
two
four
five
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but I found using a for loop performs as expected.

```
function Get-Array {

    [CmdletBinding(
        SupportsShouldProcess=$false, ConfirmImpact='Medium'
    )]
    param(

        [string[]] $myArray

    )

    begin{

        Set-StrictMode -Version latest

        Write-Verbose ('[{0}] Processing begun ...' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand)

        Write-Verbose ("Procesing {0} items" -f $myArray.Count)

    }

    process{
`
        for($i=0;$i -lt $myArray.Count;$i++) {

            if($myArray[$i] -eq "three"){

               try
               {
                    Get-Item -Path "x:\foo" -ErrorAction Stop
               }
               catch [System.Exception]
               {
                    Write-Error $myArray[$i]
                    continue;
               }
            } 


            Write-Output $myArray[$i]
        }


    }

    end{

        Write-Verbose ('[{0}] Processing completed.' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand)
    }

}


$input = @("one","two","three","four","five")



$result = Get-Array -myArray $input -verbose -InformationVariable $info
$result 

# Expect: "one","two","four","five"
# Actual: "one","two"
```